# How to make the ThreadToken for a StateMachine available to and verifiable by every participant?

Tags: statemachines

In a StateMachine, TreadToken can be used for uniquely identifying the "genuine" UTxO sitting at the validator script of the StateMachine. A TreadToken is automatically created when the StateMachine is created by the first participant (wallet).

My question is how the other participants (wallets) can get the ThreadToken created for the StateMachine? Besides, when a participant somehow receives a ThreadToken, how can he/she verify that the received the TreadToken received is authentic?

Answer (score 0):

They have to check that the state token is minted with the default minting policy.
The default minting policy and SM validator are coupled so that if this is verifiable, then all is well.

> A TreadToken is automatically created when the StateMachine is created by the first participant (wallet).

Not necessarily. You can "Start" a SM by sending a UTXO to an address that corresponds to a SM. This is precisely why you might want to verify that the the thread token is an NFT.

If the default minting policy is not used then they'll need to do more homework. Again this might be fine. It might not.

It's possible to replace the default minting policy with a non-parameterized minting policy that shoe horns the uniqueness into the token name only.
In this case it would be much easier for a user to verify uniqueness, provided a trusted source has already verified "This CS will only make NFTs"

(policyId is a synonym for currency symbol)

An aside. It might also be desirable that the thread tokens aren't NFTs.
More generally, there are many ways you might want to modify the implementation of statemachine as available in Plutus. Its just one way to do it.

Comment: Thanks. But is it possible to derive the currency symbol of the default thread token from its state machine?